# "gnome-session-properties" says it's not installed when it is. How do I solve this?

Tags: apt

I tried entering the command `gnome-session-properties` in the run dialog but it returned *"command not found"*, so I took it to the terminal where it says it's not installed:

```
cmp@r45c:~$ gnome-session-properties
The program 'gnome-session-properties' is currently not installed. You can
install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin
cmp@r45c:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-session-bin is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
cmp@r45c:~$ gnome-session-properties
The program 'gnome-session-properties' is currently not installed. You can 
install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin
cmp@r45c:~$
```

**edit:**
Output for `grep cmp /etc/passwd`

```
cmp@r45c:~$ grep cmp /etc/passwd
pzj:x:1000:1000:Cheddie Merai,,,:/home/cmp:/bin/bash
cmp@r45c:~$
```

I have also reinstalled `gnome-session` via synaptic.

How do I solve this? If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.

Comment: Is your machine up to date?

Comment: Yes, it is up-to-date besides the 9: `bsdutils` `libblkid1` `libmount1` `libuuid1` `libuuid1:i386` `man-db` `mount` `util-linux` `uuid-runtime`.

Comment: @CheddieMerai Why aren't those up to date?

Comment: That bug looks like your problem. Make sure you mark yourself as affected! @g_p Why don't you add that as an answer? Try to flesh it out a bit.

Comment: I have marked myself as an affectee aswell. Thank you @g_p

Comment: @rubo77 I have edited the question to include this information.

Comment: It would be nice to find a workaround though. Did you rename the user `pzj` to `cmp` or visa-versa somehow? This could be the cause of the bug. Or did you change the PROMPT to `cmp@...`? If not, try `sudo su pzj` and then start `gnome-session-properties`. If you find a workaround, you should post it at the bugreport at launchpad

Comment: @rubo77 I just changed the prompt. I have already marked myself as an affectee of the bug.

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I guess your problem is, that you are the user `pzj` but your home folder is in `/home/cmp` which causes the problem. Try a symlink maybe: `ln -s /home/cmp /home/pzj`

Comment: This is not the problem. Refer to my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like bug and  has already been reported.

See [bug #1310003](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1310003) on Launchpad.

You should mark yourself as an affected person by going on this bug-page and appending yourself.

Comment: **Update** I did some further research and what I came up with is that it's not a bug. It was removed in GNOME 3.12 _"which is the version I have"_. see post: [gnome-session-properties removed from GNOME 3.12?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180282#p1406517)